# Google Firebase: HTTP Error: 401, The entered credentials were incorrect

Tags: node.js, firebase

I am just getting started with Firebase. I logged in using `firebase login` and it says I am logged in. I used `firebase init` to create a new project, used hosting option, and used the default firebase application. When I went to deploy using `firebase deploy` it said "The entered credentials were incorrect".

I'm not sure where I went wrong. To set up, I used `brew install npm` and then `npm install -g firebase-tools` (I'm on a mac).

I found some posts saying the project ID could be incorrect in the .firebaserc file, but it looks correct when compared to the `firebase list` output.

It looks like the default HTML that was generated will probably work, but it just won't deploy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer for this. When you tell it to use the default project, if you say firebase deploy, it tries to deploy to the default project's host system.

To fix it, create a project on the firebase server, init the firebase project (pointed at the new project name) and that will allow you to push to the server.